# The lower bound of acceptance rate for independent Metropolis–Hastings algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, accept-reject

In comparison with rejection sampling, for independent M-H algorithm, if there is a constant C such that$$f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{\int p(x)dx} \leqslant Cg(x)$$
for all x, then the acceptance rate is at least 1/C whenever the chain is in stationary; namely,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(U\leqslant \alpha(X, Y))&=\iint \min \bigg\{\frac{f(y)g(x)}{f(x)g(y)}, 1\bigg\} f(x)g(y)dxdy \\
&=2\iint I \bigg\{\frac{f(y)g(x)}{f(x)g(y)} \geqslant 1\bigg\} f(x)g(y)dxdy \\
&\geqslant \frac{2}{C}\iint I \bigg\{\frac{f(y)g(x)}{f(x)g(y)} \geqslant 1\bigg\} f(x)f(y)dxdy \\
&\geqslant \frac{2}{C} \mathbb{P} \bigg (\frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)} \geqslant \frac{f(X)}{g(X)} \bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{C}
\end{align*}
U follows a standard uniform distribution U[0, 1], g(x) is the proposal distribution while f(x) is the target distribution.

Therefore the final statement is, if f (x) ≤ ag (x), then the independent M-H will accept at least 1/a of the proposals.

I have problem with understanding the last three lines of the proof; namely,
\begin{align*}
&\geqslant \frac{2}{C}\iint I \bigg\{\frac{f(y)g(x)}{f(x)g(y)} \geqslant 1\bigg\} f(x)f(y)dxdy \\
&\geqslant \frac{2}{C} \mathbb{P} \bigg (\frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)} \geqslant \frac{f(X)}{g(X)} \bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{C}
\end{align*}

p.s. For rejection sampling we have proved that its acceptance rate is equal to $\frac{1}{C}$.

Comment: If 1/C denotes an acceptance rate (min 0, max 1), then C >= 1, and so 2 >= 2/C. This explains the first of the last three lines.

I(f(Y)/g(Y) >= f(X)/g(X)) evaluates to 1 whenever the condition is true, 0 otherwise. The integration gives the probability of that condition: all X and Y are evaluated, weighted by their probabilities, and if the condition is true we add the probability of the (x, y) combination. This is the second of the three statements.

To reach the third, we need to show that P() is 1/2.